# Deploying Laravel App on Shared hosting securely

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, security, shared-hosting

It seems there are a lot of different approaches to deploying a laravel application on shared hosting based on some googling. I understand it's different per hosting provider, but I'm looking for a simple and secure way to do this.

Right now I have a symlink from `/home/username/laravel-src/public` to `/home/username/public_html`. This gets my application on my domain, although under the public route (ie. `www.domain-name.com/public`). I can fix this easily by updating my `.htaccess` file in my `public_html` director to the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've seen this suggested in other posts, but people are saying this is not a secure approach and I'm wondering why? Isn't this just redirecting requests from `/` to `/public` internally? None of the `src` or `env` files are exposed...are they??

And if there are security concerns around this, is there at all a secure way to deploy a laravel app to shared hosting?

Comment: If you have any option to please try not to deploy larval on shared hosting, it is better and easier to deploy on even a $5 Digital Ocean VPS.

Comment: Are there resources out there that explain why this is?

Comment: Just reading up on guides that try to explain how it works, there will always be comments stating not to do it cause it will cause you nothing but headache. Laravel is not made for shared hosting. Thinks like migrations and seeders don't work. You can't use artisan commands etc.